# Error fetching app record: Problem while uploading build on test flight App store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

[image]
*Screenshot of xcode while uploading using product >> archive.

[image]
*Screenshot of Transporter app.

Xcode shows build uploaded successfully but not visible on test flight (Even after waiting for 2-3 days).

Tried to upload build using Transporter app but getting errors as shown in above screenshots and delivery logs below:

INFO: ContentDelivery version 2.14.8 (14038).
INFO: Show Progress: Contacting Apple Services…
ERROR: 404: received status code REQUEST CREATE CONTAINER (ASSET_UPLOAD); not found

I am confused what exactly is this error and what to do in order to solve this.

Comment: Login again in Xcode with your app store credential and try again

Comment: @JasminSojitra still not working.

Comment: @JasminSojitra do you know any other option to try?

Comment: No, I did that and it's working on my side.